# FileUpload não carrega o listener no JSF 2.2

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Estou migrando um projeto para JEE7 de PrimeFaces 3.5 para 5.0 e estou com um problema no FileUpload. Não carrega o arquivo no listener do evento do JSF 2.2.

Segue o codigo do xhtml:

```
<p:fileUpload id="import" value="#{fileBean.file}" mode="single" 
    label="#{msg.procurar}" 
    auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload}"
    invalidFileMessage="#{msg.somente_excel}"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/" />
```

Segue o bean:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
      this.uploadedFile = event.getFile();
}
```

Alguém tem ideia do porquê o evento não está sendo disparado? O JSF2.2 mudou alguma configuração ou propriedade ?

Comment: O que chega no parâmetro do método?

Comment: coloquei uma saida para o console no  enent.getFie() ma não mostrou nada pois não está disparando o evento.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que eu percebi aqui, você tem retirar o **value**, já que o valor vai ser tratado pelo **Listener**.

Além disso, o mode tá errado, você colocou **single**, mas o certo é **simple**